# Androidx customize navigationItem selected action

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer activity with android studio template (Navigation Drawer Activity). Now in androidx & `android studio 3.5.3` they have changed the implementation of navigation drawer activity. in the java class the implementation looks like

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

And `onCreateOptionsMenu` take `ContextMenu`, `View` and `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` instead of just `Menu`

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer_main, menu);
    }
```

But there is no `onOptionsItemSelected` or `onContextItemSelected` method. So my question is if I want to customize the drawer item click event, how can I do that? suppose I want to pass intentExtra to the fragment or I have to check variable value on specific item click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX Drawer Navigation implementation is quiet easy as before

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupNavigation();
    }
    private void setupNavigation() {
        // link Toggle button with Drawer
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
            {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    //drawerOpened = false;
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    //drawerOpened = true;
                }
            };
            drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        // Create Menu for NavigationView
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        menu.add(category.getName());
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(category.getIcon());
        menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // TODO; Here's your sexy looking codes ;P must return false if you don't know what `true` do

                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the job with `addOnDestinationChangedListener`. In this method you can switch for the ids, you have given in `AppBarConfiguration.Builder` method. In my implementation I'm hiding or showing a layout based on the click event.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                             @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
            //item with id nav_home found do your work
            main_activity_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nav Home Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
            main_activity_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestChangeElse!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
  });
```